# Unable to get value of the property 'addCls': object is null or undefined ext-all-debug.js, line 15874 character 9

Tags: browser, extjs, compatibility

Am getting the following error, when i try to use my EXTJS code on IE 8, while it works fine on mozilla and IE 9

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'addCls': object is null or undefined 
ext-all-debug.js, line 15874 character 9

the pointer in debugger goes to -
        el.addCls(me.initCls()); in ext-all-debug.js

am new to extjs, hence kinda bogged down by what really is the prob,
have checked for any syntax errors.

Comment: (Zombie Q, I know) What version of Ext?

Comment: I see this problem in IE 9 with Ext JS 5